# Cannot monkey-patch generic objects

Tags: python, generics, monkeypatching

I encountered strange behavior trying to monkey-patch a generic object (e.g. `List[str]`) in Python 3.6. Basically, assigning to an attribute of a generic object causes all instances of the same to be modified.

```
from typing import List

list_str = List[str]
list_int = List[int]

list_str.foo = 1
list_int.foo = 2

print(list_str.foo)  # 2 <-- WHAT?
print(list_int.foo)  # 2
```

Why does this happen? Can I work around it?

It's not like `__getitem__` sneakily returns the same object:

```
print(id(list_str))  # 2007605720376
print(id(list_int))  # 2007622803912
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/typing.py#L1164-L1173) of the metaclass `GenericMeta`, this is clearly intentional. When setting an attribute on any instance that is "fully constructed" (`List[str]` rather than `List`), this gets redirected to the base class (`List`):

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    # We consider all the subscripted generics as proxies for original class
    if (
        attr.startswith('__') and attr.endswith('__') or
        attr.startswith('_abc_') or
        self._gorg is None  # The class is not fully created, see #typing/506
    ):
        super(GenericMeta, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
    else:
        super(GenericMeta, self._gorg).__setattr__(attr, value)
```

It should be added that attribute setting will alias even with normal class attribute, not just monkey-patching. Setting a class attribute in a class method will set the attribute for the generic superclass and all its subclasses.

Also, note that `GenericMeta` will be gone in Python 3.7, but it appears that [attribute aliasing will remain](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/typing.py#L708-L712):

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
    if _is_dunder(attr) or attr in ('_name', '_inst', '_special'):
        super().__setattr__(attr, val)
    else:
        setattr(self.__origin__, attr, val)
```

In either case, the source code provides a clear workaround—make the attribute a dunder:

```
list_str = List[str]
list_int = List[int]

list_str.__foo__ = 1
list_int.__foo__ = 2

print(list_str.__foo__) # 1
print(list_int.__foo__) # 2
```